# Jhipster gateway Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: java, api, web-services, authentication, jhipster

Hello all i am working on Jhipster on ubuntu os.
my project set up was done sucessfully.
but when trying to test apis it gives me error of authentication.

here is the error occurred while testing API. it will be pleasure if someone help me out.

Error:

```
rExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

Web Browser

```
{
"type" : "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
"title" : "Unauthorized",
"status" : 401,
"detail" : "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
"path" : "/api/account",
"message" : "error.http.401"
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with more details like JHipster version, type of authentication, type of application, ... Why do you think it's an error? 401 is normal for protected endpoints when not authenticated.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou what else you need to understand this error...??

Comment: Simply answer the questions I asked in comment above and also how you test. Edit your question rather than answering in comments, it's easier to read

Comment: @GaëlMarziou i got solution thank you for giving your valuable time.

Comment: OK, so please add solution here for others or delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the default configuration of Jhipster user creation.
When we create app and entity using Jhipster then it also create user authentication as their functionality.
But in my case user was not created in database which I selected during creation.

Responsible Tables:

1. jhi_user
2. jhi_user_authority
3. jhi_authority

So, We just need to provide details of default user of Jhipster in these tables.

**Username: admin

Password: admin**

make sure password is in encrypted form.

Comment: I got the same error , but what if I am not using databases at all ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case *(in dev profile)*, i update the **JWT token**, changing to base64 in all the applications (microservice, gateway and registry), additionally, comment the old property *"secret"* and use the same key in all. Then test the API from the gateway correctly, without authorization problems.

*jh version 5.7.1*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you execute your JHipster registry with authentication and your application without.
In case you didn't change your JHipster jwt secret key you have to execute your application(microservice) with next parameters:

```
--spring.security.user.password=admin --jhipster.security.authentication.jwt.secret=my-secret-key-which-should-be-changed-in-production-and-be-base64-encoded --spring.cloud.config.server.composite.0.type=native --spring.cloud.config.server.composite.0.search-locations=file:./central-config
```

> You secret JWT key you could find in central-config package in application.yml file

For more details read JHipster documentation : 
https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#-json-web-tokens-jwt
https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when trying to login after I generated the app. The tests ran fine.

Deleting the target folder and rebuilding the whole project seemed to solve it.